# VBO GL_STREAM_DRAW double buffer or new buffer?

Tags: opengl, vbo

There is some conflicting information on the STREAM usage specifier.

[Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html) states you should use double buffering and update the stream buffer that is not being read by the GPU.

[OpenGL's reference documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBufferData.xml) states you should only modify the contents of the buffer once. Which implies you should create a new buffer to write data instead of reusing the existing buffer.

Is there a reason to use the more complicated double buffering technique?

Comment: [Ignore both and read this.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming)

Answer (score -2):

This is what I've experienced:

GL_STATIC_DRAW - for static content, which never changing (examples: terrain, buildings)

GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW - for spontaneously changing data (examples: skybox, units, characters, anything that relies on actual input)

GL_STREAM_DRAW - for constantly updating data (examples: some 2D text like FPS counter, particles)

You can have a tiny FPS drop if you choose the wrong usage.

Comment: This doesn't address the question which was asked.